# Bug with php file converted from ansi to utf-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have a few php scripts files encoded in ANSI. Now that I converted my website to html5, I need everything in UTF-8, so that accents in these file are displayed correctly without any php conversion through iconv(). I used Notepad++ to set the encoding of my scripts on UTF-8 and save the files, and most are fine, accents are displayed correctly, only the main script now blocks everything, and the server only returns a white page, without any error message, even with `ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_ALL')` !

When I change the encoding back to ANSI in Notepad++, and save the file without any other change, it works again (except the accents are not displayed correctly without iconv() ).

I did also try to use a php script to change the encoding with `...$file = iconv('ISO-8859-1','UTF-8', $file);...` but the result is exactly the same !

I wrote a short php script to look for high char() values, but the highest values seems to be usual French accents like é, è, etc which are also present on other files and pose no problem. I did remove other special chars, without any effect...

The problem is that the file is large, more than 4500 lines and I'm not sure how to proceed to correct this ? Anyone has had this problem, or has any idea ?

Comment: In Notepad++, are you actually converting the file, or just changing the encoding you're viewing it with?

Comment: I am pretty sure you are taking the wrong approach. Your PHP files should not be utf-8. The strings etc can be, try using byte escape sequences.

Comment: wye, I convert then save. If I just change the encoding, accents appear as strange codes xE8, xA3, etc.

Comment: Did you tried the "UTF-8 without BOM" (Or something like that, language change, sorry) option? The BOM made some errors appear to me once with another app.

Comment: Yes, I did, with the same result...

Comment: beiller, that's the problem, I want to use French for the strings, not escaped or html codes. Even if all content is stored in the DB, there are still a few titles and words which are static on the website, and stored inside the functions in this file.

Comment: Could something be dome with a binary editor ? Looking for out of UT-8 range characters, or "headers", something like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the "£" (pound) character, I used it a lot as delimiter in preg_match("£(...)£", "...", $string) and preg_replace conditions.

For some reason these characters were not accepted after conversion. I had to replace all of them, then only it worked fine in utf-8... Apparently they are not a problem now that the file is converted, I can use them again.